# I have 2 androids saving doc is my problem

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, external-sd, insufficient-memory, documents

I want to write a doc or text in my program that came installed on my devices and save it to my 32 gig micro sd that my tablet now recognizes. HOw do I do that?

Comment: What is the name of this program (hyperlink too)? Can you not somehow select/see the location as your SD card when you try to save the doc/text file?  You've added [tag:insufficient-memory] tag which is often the case only when device is having low memory issues (system messages of such). Please [edit] and remove this tag if there is no such issue. Also mention the details I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application, there should be an option in the settings that allows you to choose your storage medium. If that option is not there, then I suggest saving it on the cloud. Moving manually may not work the way you want. If you do want to move it manually, then download [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro). From there, navigate to the default folder (each application may be different and because you haven't told us the application name, I can't help you there). Find the file you desire to move and from there it should be obvious.